# Have only 1 column scroll while rest are sticky on Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

I want a Navbar and 3 column layout where only the center column scrolls and the rest stay on the screen. (nav and left and right column are sticky) Also the left and right column should collapse on mobile (which they do)

Here is what I have

```
<nav> //lots of stuff here </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class ="row">

         <div class ="col-md-2 sticky-top">
         </div>

         <div class ="col-md-8">
         //this should be the scrollable column.
         </div>

         <div class ="col-md-2 sticky-top">
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I have been trying the 'sticky-top' bootstrap class to no success.

Comment: Use class `overflow-auto` where scolling is allowed and `overflow-hidden` where it is not. Details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/overflow/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap `sticky-top` `div` inside your `col` `div`

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="p-3"> //lots of stuff here </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="sticky-top">
        Fixed content //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci iem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis
        expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. r rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis
      animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum
      sed dignissimos. //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam
      eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat exercitationem laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis explicabo obcaecati pariatur rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem
      odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. //this should be the
      scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat exercitationem laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis explicabo obcaecati pariatur rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Quaerat exercitationem laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis explicabo obcaecati pariatur rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat exercitationem
      laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis explicabo obcaecati pariatur rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat
      quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae
      alias nemo delectus adipisci ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat exercitationem laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis
      explicabo obcaecati pariatur rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque
      ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos. //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci
      ipsum placeat quo obcaecati quia blanditiis ad quis itaque sit enim impedit illo, veniam eos dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat exercitationem laboriosam expedita, odio perferendis explicabo obcaecati pariatur
      rerum quasi odit debitis. Quo blanditiis perferendis animi pariatur quod! Odit, exercitationem odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium
      cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos.
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 ">
      <div class="sticky-top">
        Fixed content //this should be the scrollable column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestiae alias nemo delectus adipisci iem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At vero vitae rem quaerat quod reiciendis
        expedita itaque ipsum unde magnam nisi laudantium cumque cupiditate aspernatur, provident dicta, dolorum sed dignissimos.
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```